# java.net.sockettimeout exception: Read Timed Out

Tags: java, exception, java-io

I am reading the "interests" of a user using Facebook API.

When I am trying to read the URL using the following code, I am getting java.net.sockettimeoutexception:

```
public static String readURL(URL url) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    con.setReadTimeout(20000);
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    int r;
    while ((r = is.read()) != -1) {
        baos.write(r);
    }
    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
    }
```

How can I handle this now? What should I do?

Comment: provide detailed error stack trace.

Comment: Do you know where it is? I saw it on the Tomcat window and it got closed.

Comment: Your apache-tomcat/logs/localhost.2012-05-24.log

Comment: Either you socket timeout is too short, in which case you should increase it, or it isn't too short, in which case you detected the timeout that you wanted to detect. What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the values of:

```
con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
con.setReadTimeout(20000);
```

and add a catch for that exception.